# How to set the display precision of the edge length to 0.01mm?

Tags: interface, edges

How to set the display precision of the edge length to 0.01mm?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it might be hardcoded to 3 significant digits, Measureit addon allows to increase precision to 5 decimal places, but you need to explicitly add the measurement for each edge… Also Mesh Tools addon allows to set edge length and there it displays more accurate current edge length.

Comment: yes, i know Mesh Tools addon to set edge length, But it also only shows 3 digits, Measureit addon is a very troublesome tool, blender original settings can not set the accuracy, that only so

Comment: For me it shows 3 decimal digits on top: https://i.imgur.com/S5cG8sP.png and 4 decimal digits on bottom and 1 more if I click the field https://i.imgur.com/AmcpLGg.png.

Comment: If you don't mind doing some converting you could simply do the following: under _Scene Properties_ > _Units_ either switch the setting for _Length_ from _Millimeters_ to _Micrometers_, so instead of 19.3 mm it would then show e.g. 19314 μm, or (which would of course show an "upscaled" value) switch the _Unit Scale_ from 1 to 1000, in this case it would show 19314 mm instead of 19.3 mm, which would just require you to keep in mind it is multiplied by 1000. For even more decimal places accuracy you could additionally change the _Length_ to _Micrometers_ and get something like 19314267 μm.

Comment: yes，I've used the method you mentioned to convert to μm. But it looks confusing because I often have to compare my vernier calipers in real life, so it's not very convenient ，and come to ask this question.